# First border entry in the Schengen area is different than the application

Tags: schengen, sweden

I am going to Sweden. I got a tourist visa issued by the Swedish embassy. During my application, I chose "Sweden" as my first border entry. I am not sure if I could leave it blank. Now I am going to buy a ticket from Canada to Sweden and just figured that there is no direct flight from Canada to Sweden. Hence, it is necessary to have a stop in one another Schengen country (e.g., France, Netherlands, ...).

Will I face any problem at the border?

Comment: Technically, it is not necessary to stop in another Schengen country, as flights to Arlanda through Heathrow (BA) or Newark (SAS) are available. Since you didn't mention your country of origin, we cannot determine whether such connections are available without additional visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schengen visa may be issued for any or all Schengen states. That's mentioned on the visa, if it says simply "Schengen States" in the language of the issuing nation that means that **in principle** you can visit any Schengen states. Of course you are not allowed to **lie** in your application, and that is where selecting Sweden as port of entry could become sticky, but you are allowed to make minor changes to your itinerary after the application.

So there will be no problem if you arrive at one of the major airports with onward tickets to Sweden and clear proof that you are merely switching planes in France or the Netherlands..